# for loop are not executing

Tags: php, mysqli

HI I have a for loop that loops through ids. For one of other reason the for loop is not executing.

```
$med_uuids = $_POST['med_uuids'];

$med_uuids_length = count($med_uuids);

for($x=0; $x < $med_uuids_length; $x++){
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM medicine WHERE uuid = 
    '$med_uuids[$x]'");
}

//close connection to db
mysqli_close($connection);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which data you get in the $med_uuids variable ?post example data

Comment: If `$_POST['med_uuids'];` really is an array, try using `foreach()`; then you don't need to worry about missing keys. If it isn't an array, then you need to make it one

Comment: can you put a echo $med_uuids_length before the loop to see if it has the correct value?

Comment: Are you sure that your $_POST['med_uuids'] is an array. Because count can only use with an array.

Comment: Side point, would it not be better to build the query and execute outside of the loop to avoid multiple queries?

Comment: when i echo the $med_uuids, I get 05913c56-ab81-43d4-8de7-9019d5e1230a,f9a00986-a0e4-4c92-8089-9c451e10ff5e,f8881ff5-515b-4e59-8d5f-d7f8b04586f3 and if I echo the $med_uuids_length I get 1

Comment: I think it's executing well, it's just your query that is not working. Try  "DELETE FROM medicine WHERE uuid = 
    '" . $med_uuids[$x] . "'"

Comment: @Skillie Please beware of SQL injection also with the solution that you accepted (the one with `explode`). If someone input this `10' OR '1'='1'` he would delete all! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: thanks I will definitely go look at sequel injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no array, but just a string.

```
$ids = explode(',', $_POST['med_uuids']); // make an array

foreach ($ids as $id) {
    mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM medicine WHERE uuid = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $id) . "'");
}
```

Comment: You can also use the trick of naming the parameter `med_uuids[]` (with square brackets). This way `$_POST['med_uuids[]']` will be an array, an you'll not need to do an `explode`.

Comment: @ClaudioVenturini: he had probably only one input and put there IDs separated by comma. Your solution needs more inputs (eg. dynamically added). It's better solution, but we don't know how much the OP can manage their HTML.

Comment: Maybe you're right, my answer was simply a hint to the OP in case he can freely change how data are acquired :)

Answer (score 0):

If you get a comma separated list like this (124,121,45,12,35), then you can do something like this

```
DELETE FROM medicine WHERE uuid IN (124,121,45,12,35)
```

This will help you do the task in one go and your DB will not be clogged with multiple queries.